# Can people learn without examples?

Tags: learning, psychology

When learning various topics (math comes to mind as a good example), to what extent is information retained/understood affected by whether or not examples of the concept or process are provided?
For example, I was learning about encryption and absorbed quite a few whitepapers, but nothing stuck until I came across an implementable example. Is there an underlying physical/psychological reason for this?

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  Much of the first half of the twentieth century was dedicated to research on learning without examples (conditioning).  The example provided in the question is a "worked example", so maybe you are asking about the [worked example effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worked-example_effect)?